# Get image from "google form" file upload item

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

we are trying to make a google form to which makes a project report with some pictures on a google doc , string responses are no problem , as we can easily manipulate them and replace some text in a google doc template , the question is how to retrieve an image file via google apps script to insert this into google doc via "Onsubmit Form script"

I leave code we are currently using to retrieve responses from google forms

P.D. we have a google Business account , if that helps in something!

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var formResponse = e.response;
  // If all questions are required, getItemResponses returns responses in form-order
  var itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();
  var imgResponse = formResponse.getResponses();
  var project_name = itemResponses[0].getResponse();  

  var client = itemResponses[1].getResponse();
  var delivery_date = itemResponses[2].getResponse();
  var supervisor = itemResponses[3].getResponse();
  var net_worth = itemResponses[4].getResponse();
  var description = itemResponses[5].getResponse();
  var pictures = itemResponses[6].getResponse(); // returns a string "[Ljava.lang.Object;@68c638d4", how to get image URL??
  var client_name = itemResponses[7].getResponse();
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

This will rename your files for you and write timestamp, name and id into a spreadsheet. In this case the e.values[1] was a comma separated list of files that were uploaded.

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  var ft=e.values.slice(1);
  var fA=ft[0].split(',');
  for(var i=0;i<fA.length;i++) {
    var file=DriveApp.getFileById(fA[i].slice(fA[i].indexOf("=")+1));
    var t=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "HHmmss")
    file.setName(Utilities.formatString('Cooper-%s',t));
    SpreadsheetApp.openById("id").getSheetByName("UploadFiles").appendRow([e.values[0],file.getName(),file.getId()]);
  } 
}
```